# Tree recursion - Print subsequence of a given number

Tags: algorithm, go, recursion, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

## Problem statement:

```
// m is the number, n is upto-length of subsequences
// m = 20125, n =3  should print 201, 202, 205, 212, 215, 225, 012, 015, 125
// m = 20125, n =2 should print 20, 21, 22, 25, 01, 02, 05, 12, 15, 25
// m = 20125, n =1 should print 2, 0, 1, 2, 5
// m = 20125, n =4 should print 2012, 2015, 2125, 0125, 2025
// m = 20125, n =5 should print 20125
```

---

Below is the recursive solution implemented in GoLang:

```
package recursion

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// m is the number, n is upto-length of subsequences
// m = 20125, n =3  should print 201, 202, 205, 212, 215, 225, 012, 015, 125
// m = 20125, n =2 should print 20, 21, 22, 25, 01, 02, 05, 12, 15, 25
// m = 20125, n =1 should print 2, 0, 1, 2, 5
// m = 20125, n =4 should print 20125

func PrintSubSequence(m int, n int) {

    numDigits := digits(m)

    if n >= 1 && numDigits >= n { // m != 0
        for i := 1; i <= numDigits-n+1; i++ { // tree recurion
            firstInvocToIter := true
            var slice []string
            var findSubSequence func(int, int)

            findSubSequence = func(m int, n int) {

                if n == 1 { // base case
                    for m != 0 {
                        slice = append(slice, strconv.Itoa(m%10))
                        m = m / 10
                    }
                    return
                } else {
                    if firstInvocToIter {
                        firstInvocToIter = false
                        findSubSequence(m/tenToThePower(i), n-1)
                    } else {
                        findSubSequence(m/10, n-1)
                    }

                    for i, value := range slice {
                        slice[i] = value + strconv.Itoa(m%10)
                    }
                }

            }
            findSubSequence(m, n) // (20125, 3)
            fmt.Println(slice)
        }

    } else {
        return
    }

    PrintSubSequence(m/10, n)
}

func tenToThePower(times int) int {
    number := 1
    for times > 0 {
        number *= 10
        times--
    }
    return number
}

// Return the number of the digits of positive integer n
func digits(n int) int {
    if n <= 0 {
        return 0
    } else if n < 10 {
        return 1
    } else {
        allButLast, _ := split(n)
        return digits(allButLast) + 1
    }
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/myhub/cs61a/recursion"
)

func main() {

    recursion.PrintSubSequence(20125, 2) // prints duplicates as per debugging
    recursion.PrintSubSequence(20125, 3) // Works fine 
}
```

---

For `recursion.PrintSubSequence(20125, 3)` output is fine:

```
[125 025 225]
[015 215]
[205]
[012 212]
[202]
```

For `recursion.PrintSubSequence(20125, 2)` output has duplicates(**problem output**):

```
[25 15 05 25]        --> Valid
[15 05 25] --> duplicate
[05 25] --> duplicate
[25] --> duplicate
[12 02 22]           --> Valid
[02 22] --> duplicate
[22] --> duplicate
[01 21]              --> Valid
[21] --> duplicate
[20]                 --> Valid
```

---

Does this require maintaining a set of strings? to include `slice` in a set

or

How to handle duplicates? Looks like `n==1` base case of tree recursion is giving issue?

Comment: For 20125 , 25 at comes twice as subsequence , if you want to ignore duplicate remove duplicate digit and try to generate subsequence

Comment: @Eklavya first entry in the problem output has two times mention ing 25. What about the second entry? Which is actual duplicate...

Comment: That is obviously duplicate

Comment: @Eklavya So, my question is, how to avoid those duplicates in the above code?

Comment: I think best to rewrite your code, are you want to remove all duplicate ? means two times 25 is valid for your input. I will try to post a new way to this if you want

Comment: @Eklavya I never said twotimes 25 is invalid. Infact am not referring to that point anywhere in my query. I shown arrows for duplicate entries... I don't know, why you are behind those two times 25... Please post your recursive solution to this problem, wil go through

Comment: I understand. I post a recursive solution

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your integer into string then it will more easier I think.

```
func PrintSubSequence(digits string, tmp string, idx int, sz int) {
    if len(tmp) == sz {  // if size reach then print
        fmt.Println(tmp)
        return
    }
    // here idx indicate in tmp string we already use till idx-1
    for i := idx; i < len(digits); i++ {
        tmp2 := tmp + string(digits[i]) // Add new digit in new variable to pass in recursion without change current tmp
        PrintSubSequence(digits, tmp2, i+1, sz)
    }
}
func main() {
    PrintSubSequence(strconv.Itoa(21025), "", 0, 2) // Convert interger into string
}
```

Full code in go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/9negtrSPiog)

Comment: Can you indicate, what `tmp2`, `tmp` & `idx` mean? Code is not readable...I need to understand, Why four arguments?

Comment: @overexchange Comments added

Comment: But the output is giving `2102`, `2105`, `2125`, `2025`, `1025` It should print output `21025`... please see the problem statement in query

Comment: You say subsequence. For `20125` they are valid subsequence of size 4 where `20125` is  not, and `n is upto-length of subsequences` thats means so

Comment: I saw that. Just asking what is the logic behind this. If you have custom case then you have to handle manually that.

Comment: I have updated the query now, for n =4 correctly. Your code is aligned with output

Answer (score 0):

**Algo here**:-

1. You need to think from a each digit perspective. 
   So, when you generating subsequence, either a digit can be part of the subsequence, or it cannot be.
2. When you consider a particular digit, increment a counter (say, currentLength).
   Add the sequence which is formed till now to a Set to avoid duplicates.
3. If the currentLength counter has reached your given upto-length, then stop the formation of current subsequence.
4. Move onto next sequence formation.

Comment: Added to array instead of set. Let me modify